# The [vendor] tag needs some love (or death)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, blocklist-request

Looking at [vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendor) questions, it appears to be an important concept in [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) ([questions tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2+vendor)). I don't know if the tag should remain in the rest of the questions. If so, perhaps the tag should be renamed to [symfony-vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-vendor), and [vendor] blacklisted.

Comment: Most of them refer to symfony, and the others are too broad or otherwise improperly tagged.  I'm not sold (yet) on the new tag, but the other inappropriate uses, should be killed with fire.

Comment: Reason a new tag is needed is that people will continue using [vendor] in a not proper manner.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the [vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendor) tag uses refer to the directory name of the PHP dependency manager (Composer). Vendor also is another name for 3rd party packages/dependencies.

As such, I believe it should be removed completely. Imo, there is no need for retagging. I'm also against introducing [symfony-vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-vendors) or [composer-php-vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php-vendors). Nobody would want to watch a specific "vendors" tag instead of the complete tag. It's like having [symfony-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-controller), [laravel-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-controller), etc.